# how does Dropbox upload my files to its server?

Tags: networking, network-protocols, dropbox

Drop Box appears to be really fast at syncing with its server. Does anyone know what algorithm it uses?

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox uses its own proprietary sync algorithm which makes dropbox faster than their competitors. It also uses delta sync algorithm for desktop clients.